# How use remote driver in Noraui?

Tags: java, noraui

I want use remote web Driver in my noraui but I don't find configuration file. I use Noraui 3.4.2. So where is this configuration? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide some more detailed information this question is very vague

Comment: I don't have other details, I just want know where is configuration file for remote web drivers in Noraui. What other information do you want ?

Comment: You want use Selenium Grid or a webdriver from your CI?

Comment: I want use Selenium Grid

Comment: is not possible, you need create a Pull Request on official GitHub